# Git - create and push repository via visual studio giving "the remote end hung up unexpectedly" error, how to fix it?

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am new to visual studio, trying "Create and push" option to create the repository and push over github, initially it was working fine but right now giving "`the remote end hung up unexpectedly`" error.
It is creating a repo over github but not pushing code.

Can anyone let me know how to fix it in visual studio?

Comment: `the remote end hung up unexpectedly` just indicates that the connection was interrupted for some undisclosed reason. Do you have any more detail you can share?